# Fragments in ViewPager - wrong index?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

I'm using a `ViewPager` to display 3 `ListFragments` of the same class, but the `ListView` content of each `Fragment` should be different depending on `Fragment`'s index.

`ListFragment`:

```
    public static NavigationListFragment newInstance(int index) {
    NavigationListFragment listFrag = new NavigationListFragment();
    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    bundle.putInt("num", index);
    listFrag.setArguments(bundle);
    Log.d("INDEX", index+"");
    return listFrag;
}
```

and the `FragmentPagerAdapter`:

```
    @Override
public Fragment getItem(int index) {
    return NavigationListFragment.newInstance(index);
}

    @Override
public int getCount() {
    return TITLES.length;
}

@Override
public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
    return TITLES[position];
}
```

The problem: at the start I immediately get `INDEX 0` and `INDEX 1` logged, when I swipe to the 2nd item inside the Pager it shows `INDEX 2` and *doesn't show anything* for the last one. The title (I'm using a `TabStrip`) however is set correctly for each page.

Why is the `getItem()` method called 2 times for the first page, but isn't called at all for the last one?

**UPDATE**
I figured out I can't rely on `getItem()` method since it gets called to preload multiple `Fragments`. So the question is now how can I safely determine the position of a Fragment before setting up its `ListView`?

**UPDATE 2**
I ended up creating 3 `Fragment` classes and instantiating them based on index, but somehow I feel this is an ugly solution, I'd be thankful for a more elegant one.

Answer (score 1):

`ViewPager` creates nearest items for swipe animation purpose. So first time when activity attaches `ViewPager` user should see first fragment and can swipe to second one. When user swiped `ViewPager` creates third one and user can swipe again.

1. attachment of `ViewPager`
2. `ViewPager` creates first and second items - user see first fragment
3. swipe begin - user see transition between first and second
4. swipe end - user see second fragment
5. `ViewPager` creates third item
6. swipe begin - user see transition between second and third
7. swipe end - user see third fragment
8. `ViewPager` destroys first fragment and create fourth
9. etc

Comment: well that makes sense, I came to almost to the same conclusion after logging everything possible. But the question is, how can I ensure the correct content when setting up the `ListView` in the `onActivityCreated()` method? I really don't think that the only way is using 3 different `Fragment` classes, there must be a way

Comment: @Droidman hm, I actually can't understand your problem and concerns about `getItem` method with `index` parameter. It's quite obvious and straightforward method of creation ViewPager's children.