# ViewPager starting at wrong place?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

I want to display letters on screen and enable swiping with `ViewPager`, however, the first letter starts at position first+1.

I have an array of drawables like this

```
private static int[] images = {R.drawable.a,R.drawable.b,R.drawable.c,R.drawable.d};
public static int position = 0;
```

And based on the position, I set the image to be shown in `ImageView`

```
letter.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(images[position]));
```

The `getPosition` code

```
@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) {
    LetterViewFragment.position = position;
    return new LetterViewFragment();
}
```

Now the initial view shows the **second** image as initial view, and when I swipe right, I see the  **second** image again. But if I swipe back from **third** image back to first, I see the first image.

I've found similar questions that had the same problem like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24839913/fragments-in-viewpager-wrong-index)
but there's no answer.

Thanks!

Comment: i request you to post whole class or fragment

Comment: Why you are using the static variable for the fragment? Instead you can pass the position to the constructor? Secondly, show the complete FragmentAdapter code

Comment: @MustansarSaeed I was originally passing it through newInstance since the regular non-default constructor is bad practice, but it still didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

Try to change you code like below:

```
letter.setImageDrawable(images[position-1]);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this code that can help you manage the latter at position which starts at position 1,

```
letter.setImageResource(images[position - 1]);
```

Comment: This won't work properly, because once I scroll to the 3rd letter and go back it throws a Null ptr exception. Also, it has the first letter for both 1'st and 2nd entry. The problem is that whatever shows first, it's also on the second position.